# Using SVG.JS to overlap two SVG Elements - one responsive, one fixed

Tags: javascript, css, svg, responsive-design, svg.js

So I am building a website using an SVG element to cover the entire viewport. I then have a responsive polygon which stretches the entire width of the viewport with some text on it. The issue I am having is such that I don't want the text to stretch, which when you use SVG.JS, the text is simply another child of the SVG canvas and in turn stretches with the viewport. I also want the text to be parallel to part of the polygon, which you can see in the diagram I have provided.

So, in a way, I need the text to respond to the SVG Polygon, but also not respond to it.

I was able to get the non-scaling text to work by creating another SVG element overlapping the original one with a preserved aspect ratio... however, as in diagram 3 of the image, I want to click the polygon for an animation, and by having another SVG canvas over the top this is not possible. Your canvas on top would appear to block the one below for onClick events, plus it's difficult to make the text parallel.

[Diagram of polygon / text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrcPA.png)

I am using SVG.JS, but if you can offer help using SVG,HTML,CSS that is also useful.

HTML:

```
<div id="maindiv">
</div>
```

JS (SVG.JS) with text created on a new canvas:

```
var draw = SVG('maindiv').viewbox('0 0 500 500').attr({ 'preserveAspectRatio': 'none' })
var polyg = draw.polygon('0,100 500,200 500,500 0,500').fill('black')

polyg.click(function() {
   this.animate().attr({'points':'0,200 500,300 500,500 0,500'})
})

var txtcanv = SVG('maindiv').style({'position':'fixed'})
var title = txtcanv.text('Tim Iland Design').font({
  family: 'Arial'
, weight: 'bold'
, size: 30
,fill: '#f06'
})
```

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I did not get the animation idea, but for a parallel text, you just should use a native approach with `textPath` element: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/svg/curved-text-along-path/. So, I'd go with single top path with animating it, as sides are always the same (expect of animation), or you could replace the entire figure with closed `path`

Comment: You can make the image on top nonclickable by using `pointer-events: none`. When someone clicks the polygon and the element is in top, it doesnt interfer

Comment: Thanks @Fuzzyma, worked perfectly!